# CakePHP Builder

Tags: php, cakephp

I have found a GUI cakePHP builder in http://www.widgetpress.com/, but it is a version for Mac. Is there a GUI CakePHP Builder for windows ?

Answer (score 8):

there is a web based builder

http://cakeapp.com/

Comment: is there desktop application ???

because I dont have Internet Connection in my house, so Its hard to develop form the web.

Comment: I have not seen one for windows. You should try the cakephp command line tool "bake" for windows. The only connection it requrires is to a database.

here's a screencast on setting it up.

http://cakephp.org/screencasts/view/6

Answer (score 5):

Just use cake bake ....

1. Set up environment variable
2. go to cmd
   3.use cake bake

For details go to the link bellow.......

[link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Cake Bake :
1. go to your local directory using cmd
**if you do not setup environment variable** then 
  2. then got to bin folder using **"cd bin**".
**otherwise

3. type cake bake**

Answer (score 0):

Setup your favourite framework with 1 file and 1 click!
https://github.com/CakeDC/oven

A plugin to discover and manage CakePHP plugins:
https://github.com/CakeDC/mixer

Install Cake + plugins tutorial:
Search in youtube for "CakeDC Mixer"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.